# Parse UTF-8 XML in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, utf-8, xmldom

I'm trying to load and parse a simple utf-8-encoded XML file in javascript using node and the `xpath` and `xmldom` packages. There are no XML namespaces used and the same XML parsed when converted to ASCII.  I can see in the debugger in VS Code that the string has embedded spaces in between each character (surely due to loading the utf-8 file incorrectly) but I can't find a way to properly load and parse the utf-8 file.

Code:

```
var xpath = require('xpath')
  , dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

const fs = require('fs');

var myXml = "path_to_my_file.xml";

var xmlContents = fs.readFileSync(myXml, 'utf8').toString();

// this line causes errors parsing every single tag as the tag names have spaces in them from improper utf-8 decoding
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xmlContents, 'application/xml');
var cvNode = xpath.select1("//MyTag", doc);

console.log(cvNode.textContent);
```

The code works fine if the file is ASCII (`textContent` has the proper data), but if it is UTF-8 then there are a number of parsing errors and `cvNode` is `undefined`.

Is there a proper way to parse UTF-8 XML in node/javascript?  I can't for the life of me find a decent example.

Comment: Have you tried `'utf8'` without the minus? That is the correct value to use for utf-8 encoding in this API. On the other hand, when you see additional white spaces between each letter this suggests that the file isn't actually encoded using utf-8 but uses an encoding with 16 bits base. Have you tried `'utf16le'`?

Comment: yes, sorry, typo.  I have tried both

Comment: @NineBerry 'utf16le' did the trick.  Thanks so much.  If you want to add an official answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see additional white spaces between each letter, this suggests that the file isn't actually encoded using utf-8 but uses a 16 bit unicode encoding.

Try `'utf16le'`.

For a list of supported encodings see [Buffers and Character Encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings).